# Datapicker for nullable DateTime binds incorrectly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datepicker, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this problem, where i have 2 properties in my project entity:

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
```

In my view i have the following code.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="prependedInput">@Resources.Project.StartDate</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-prepend">
            <input type="text" name="StartDate" class="input-small datepicker" value="@DateTime.Now.ToDateFormat()" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="prependedInput">@Resources.Project.EndDate</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-prepend">
            <input type="text" name="EndDate" class="input-small datepicker" value="@DateTime.Now.ToDateFormat()" />              
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my controller i am trying to create a new object but the ModelState.IsValid always returns false because the StartDate has a null value.

```
   public virtual ActionResult Create(Project model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Repository.Project.Add(model);
            return RedirectToAction(MVC.Project.Index());
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

How can i solve this problem and set the value of my nullable StartDate property to the date selected with datepicker ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DisplayFormat` attribute have no effect on `DateTime?` when binding data. Because of this default data binder expects the date to be in standard format f.e. `YYYY-MM-dd`.

If you want to bind datetime in diffent format use custom data binder. You can find solution here:

http://blog.greatrexpectations.com/2013/01/10/custom-date-formats-and-the-mvc-model-binder/

It should work perfectly for your problem.